# ctags with scala

Tags: scala, ctags

I am writing a [scala editor](https://github.com/asinghal) and would like to leverage ctags for method and variable lookups. A quick search on internet indicates that this may have been done before, but can not locate how.

Ideally, i would like to leverage it in conjunction with something like Exuberant Ctags but it would be great if there was something that was platform independent (Exuberant Ctags seems to be based on C ).

any help on this would be appreciated.

or should I just use apache lucene ?

Comment: using lucene and emulating ctags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as "platform independent". Java requires the java executable, which is written in C. Same thing for Python, Ruby, Perl, etc. So, as long as *there is* an exuberant-ctags available, why bother with anything else?

**EDIT**

The link I originally had here, about Scala ctags and vim tagbar, is no longer valid. I thought of replacing it with something else, but googling for "scala ctags" or "scala tagbar" yield lots of stuff, and will remain up-to-date.

Comment: thanks for your response. There surely is something called "platform independent", esp. in the context of applications. Semantics apart, what I meant was that I don't want to be creating different distributions of my scala code just because I use ctags in it, if I can avoid it. I agree with you mostly, I would like to use ctags because its proven and well, it works. The blog you pointed out, I have seen that before, but its more about leveraging tagbar in vim rather than ctags per se. Anyways, thanks for your inputs, I may just settle with ctags for all you know :-)

Comment: aww, sadly the link with instructions on how to use ctags with scala is dead

Answer (score 0):

Exuberant Ctags supports far more than just C:

```
$ ctags --list-languages
Ant
Asm
Asp
Awk
Basic
BETA
C
C++
C#
Cobol
DosBatch
Eiffel
Erlang
Flex
Fortran
HTML
Java
JavaScript
Lisp
Lua
Make
MatLab
ObjectiveC
OCaml
Pascal
Perl
PHP
Python
REXX
Ruby
Scheme
Sh
SLang
SML
SQL
Tcl
Tex
Vera
Verilog
VHDL
Vim
YACC
$
```

Perhaps extending the Java language recognizer for Scala would be a good start?

Exuberant Ctags runs on [Windows 98/NT/2000/XP](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), [VMS](http://www.polarhome.com/ctags/), and (almost every?) Unix and Unix clone. I couldn't find a list of platforms where Exuberant Ctags *doesn't* run, anyway...

Comment: sorry i meant since it seems to be coded in C, it would not be platform independent (based on my limited understanding ofcourse) - i am looking for something thats platform independent.

Comment: hi Seth, you are right in that there's an executable for every platform, but then to leverage it, I would have to release different packages for each platform. its not that bad, but I would prefer if there was something that was just one binary that worked everywhere.. i am just being lazy i guess :-)

Comment: Aha, that makes enough sense. :)